# Let $g\in C[0,1]$ and $g^{-1}(0)=K\ne\emptyset$ , closed in [0,1]. Then proof the following.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The question is

> Let $g\in C[0,1]$ and
> $g^{-1}(0)=K\ne\emptyset$.Prove that, $\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists\  G\in C[0,1]$ such that $ G^{-1}(0)$ contains an open neighborhood of $K$ and
> $\| g-G\|_\infty<\epsilon$ .

Here $\|g-G\|_\infty=\text{sup}_{x\in[0,1]}|g(x)-G(x)|$ and open neighborhood of $K$ means an open set containing $K$.
I have tried the problem in following manner. 
Let $U=g^{-1}(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. As $g$ is continuous, $U=g^{-1}(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is open and contains $K$. If $U=X$, then take $G=0$.
If $U\ne X$, then we have two disjoint non-empty closed subsets $K$ and $X\setminus U$. By Uryshon's Lemma $\exists f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $f(K)=0$ and $f(X\setminus U)=1$.
But I need to find a $G\in C[0,1]$ such that $G$ is $0$ in an open set containing $K$.
Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the "intermediate" compact set $L=g^{-1}\bigl([-\epsilon/2,\epsilon/2]\bigr)$. With Urysohn's lemma, find $f\in C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ such that $f=0$ on $L$ and $f=1$ on $X\setminus U$ and $0\leq f\leq 1$. Define $G=f\cdot g$. Clearly, $G=g$ in $(X\setminus U)\cup K$. If $x\in L\setminus K$, then $|G(x)-g(x)|=|g(x)|\leq\epsilon/2$, whereas if $x\in U\setminus L$, then
\begin{equation}
|G(x)-g(x)|=|f(x)-1|\cdot|g(x)|<1\cdot\epsilon=\epsilon
\end{equation}
In any case you have your estimate on the $\infty$-norm.

Comment: Thanks for help +1